# Redirect to another view in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When user logged in i am setting a token in localstorage if token is exists it will go the blogs page otherwise launch login page.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.login', {
      url: '/login',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
          controller:'LoginCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
.state('app.blog', {
    url: '/blog',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/blog.html',
        controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  //if token null got login
     if(window.localStorage.getItem('usertoken')==null){
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/login');
     }else{
       //go to blog
       alert('logged');
       $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/blog');
     }

});
```

I will get `alert('logged')` but it not go the `blog` view intstead it go to `login` view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(window.localStorage.getItem('usertoken')==null ? '/app/login' : '/app/blog');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make an intermediate view. Imagine dashboard.html

```
<ion-view >
  <ion-content>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Make your otherwise go there

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/dashboard');
```

And in this controller do the comprobation

```
.controller('DashboardCtrl', function($rootScope, $state) {

if(window.localStorage.getItem('usertoken')==null){
      $state.go('/app/login');
     }else{
       //go to blog
       alert('logged');
       $state.go('/app/blog');
     }
});
```